# Do same thing as sort(arrayList) without an array??? In PROCESSING

Tags: sorting, processing

Is there a way to sort ints that are not in an array?

I know you can use `sort(arrayList)` type idea with an array but example...

If I have individual variables can a similar task be done? Example, if I have three numbers can I sort them so that they print from largest to smallest?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to achieve. In Java if you have n variables a1, a2, a3...aN you can always create an array/arraylist of it. int myArray[] = {a1,a2....,aN}; and then call Arrays.sort(myArray)
If you have just 3 numbers you can write a simple if else block to find the maximum, minimum and the in-between number.

Comment: I can think of an O(n^2) algorithm. Find the maximum number print it, and mark that it has been processed. Find the next largest unmarked number and print it and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ArrayList holds objects, the type of those objects can implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) so you can use [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)' sort method. If you want, you can convert an ArrayList to an array and sort it that way, but it doesn't look like that's what you want. Here's a quick example using both methods:

```
void setup(){
  int count = 100,now;
  stroke(192,0,0);strokeWeight(count/width);
  //make up some data
  ArrayList<Pair> p = new ArrayList<Pair>();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
    Pair pair = new Pair(i,random(10,100));
    p.add(pair);
    float x = map(i,0,count,i,width);
    float y = map(pair.distance,10,100,0,50);
    line(x,50,x,50-y);
  }

  now = millis();

  //Sort typed ArrayList by converting to array first
  println("sort typed array: \n");
  Pair[] s = new Pair[p.size()];
  p.toArray(s);
  Arrays.sort(s);

  println("took " + (millis()-now) + " ms");

  now = millis();

  //Sort using Collections
  println("\n\nsorting typed array list: \n" );
  Collections.sort(p);

  println("took " + (millis()-now) + " ms");

  stroke(0,192,0);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
    Pair pair = p.get(i);
    float x = map(i,0,count,i,width);
    float y = map(pair.distance,10,100,0,50);
    line(x,100,x,100-y);
  }

}
class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{
  public int id;
  public float distance;
  Pair(int i, float d){
    id = i;
    distance = d;
  }
  int compareTo(Pair p){
    if     (p.distance > this.distance) return  1;
    else if(p.distance < this.distance) return -1;
    else return 0;
  }
  String toString(){    return id+":"+distance;    }
}
```